# Get kerberos ticket for autologin on Linux

Tags: linux, kerberos, auto-login

I tried to configure an automatic login for a user with kerberos. I tried using '`mingetty --autologin USERNAME'`, but gives me a session without a kerberos ticket (which I require to access nfs4 exports). When I do a regular login on the console with username and password I get a kerberos ticket.

I there a way to automatically login a user by using a special keytab for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great post on the Internet which I'll reference and quote below in case others find it useful for the need to accomplish anything like I needed with kerberos and ensuring a ticket is generated.

- > ### [Autologin with rc.local, su, and Kerberos](https://web.archive.org/web/20160719152720/http://jhulst.com/autologin-rclocal-su-and-kerberos)
  >
  > This past week I set up Kerberos authentication for all the machines
  >   on my network. One of those machines is our media computer which I
  >   want to login automatically and start up MythTV. In the past, I’ve
  >   used a `su – mythtv -c startx` call in /etc/rc.local to auto login.
  >
  > With the new system, I’m also mounting /home over NFS with Kerberos
  >   authentication so normally we’d need to enter in mythtv’s password
  >   before getting access to /home/mythtv as well as all the media it
  >   needs access to. So instead we need to use a keytab for the mythtv
  >   user –
  >   [http://kb.iu.edu/data/aumh.html#create](https://web.archive.org/web/20160719152720/http://kb.iu.edu/data/aumh.html#create)
  >
  > Next, we need to get the ticket into the session before trying to
  >   mount /home and start up. `su – mythtv -c “kinit mythtv@JHULST.COM -k
  >   -t /etc/mythtv.keytab”` This will error out at trying to mount /home but it will get the ticket cached for mythtv.
  >
  > After this you can then run `su – mythtv -c startx`. On my system I
  >   needed to put a sleep statement in between the two statements or else
  >   the mount would fail.
  >
  > This is somewhat insecure with the auto login thing that gives network
  >   credentials automatically. In my setup the mythtv user has limited
  >   privileges, but you’ll want to think about that before going forward
  >   with this.
- > ### [What is a keytab, and how do I use one?](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214043244/http://kb.iu.edu/data/aumh.html#create)
  >
  > **Introduction**
  >
  > A keytab is a file containing pairs of Kerberos principals and
  >   encrypted keys (these are derived from the Kerberos password). You can
  >   use this file to log into Kerberos without being prompted for a
  >   password. The most common personal use of keytab files is to allow
  >   scripts to authenticate to Kerberos without human interaction, or
  >   store a password in a plaintext file. The acquired credentials can
  >   then be used by the script to gain access to files stored in the
  >   Research File System (RFS) or Scholarly Data Archive (SDA), for
  >   example.
  >
  > **Warning:** Anyone with read permission on a keytab can use all of the keys it contains, so you must restrict and monitor permissions on
  >   any keytab files you create.
  >
  > Also, consider the following:
  >
  > - When you change your Kerberos password, you will need to recreate all
  >     your keytabs.
  > - When following the examples on this page, enter the commands exactly
  >     as they are shown.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Creating a keytab file**
  >
  > You can create a keytab file quickly on any computer with Kerberos.
  >   The keytab file is computer independent, so you can perform the
  >   process once, and then copy the file to multiple computers.
  >
  > **Note:** The following assumes you have access to a Kerberos client (either on your own workstation or on a UITS shared system, such as
  >   Quarry). You may need to modify your path to include the location of
  >   ktutil (e.g., /usr/sbin or /usr/kerberos/sbin).
  >
  > Following is an example of the keytab file creation process using MIT
  >   Kerberos:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil
  >   ktutil:  addent -password -p username@ADS.IU.EDU -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
  >   Password for username@ADS.IU.EDU: [enter your password]
  >   ktutil:  addent -password -p username@ADS.IU.EDU -k 1 -e aes256-cts
  >   Password for username@ADS.IU.EDU: [enter your password]
  >   ktutil:  wkt username.keytab
  >   ktutil:  quit
  > ```
  >
  > Following is an example using Heimdal Kerberos:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil -k username.keytab add -p username@ADS.IU.EDU -e arcfour-hmac-md5 -V 1
  > ```
  >
  > If the keytab created in Heimdal does not work, it is possible you
  >   will need an aes256-cts entry. In that case, you will need to find a
  >   computer with MIT Kerberos, and use that method instead.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Using a keytab to authenticate scripts**
  >
  > To execute a script so it has valid Kerberos credentials, use:
  >
  > ```
  >   > kinit username@ADS.IU.EDU -k -t mykeytab; myscript
  > ```
  >
  > Replace username with your username, mykeytab with the name of your
  >   keytab file, and myscript with the name of your script.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Listing the keys in a keytab file**
  >
  > With MIT Kerberos, to list the contents of a keytab file, use klist
  >   (replace mykeytab with the name of your keytab file):
  >
  > ```
  >   > klist -k mykeytab
  >
  >   version_number username@ADS.IU.EDU
  >   version_number username@ADS.IU.EDU
  > ```
  >
  > The output contains two columns listing version numbers and principal
  >   names. If multiple keys for a principal exist, the one with the
  >   highest version number will be used.
  >
  > With Heimdal Kerberos, use ktutil instead:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil -k mykeytab list
  >   mykeytab:
  >
  >   Vno  Type         Prinicpal
  >   1    des3-cbc-md5 username@ADS.IU.EDU
  >   ...
  > ```
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Deleting a key from a keytab file**
  >
  > If you no longer need a keytab file, delete it immediately. If the
  >   keytab contains multiple keys, you can delete specific keys with the
  >   ktutil command. You can also use this procedure to remove old versions
  >   of a key. An example using MIT Kerberos follows:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil
  >   ktutil: read_kt mykeytab
  >   ktutil: list
  >
  >   ...
  >
  >   slot# version# username@ADS.IU.EDU        version#
  >   ...
  >
  >   ktutil: delent slot#
  > ```
  >
  > Replace mykeytab with the name of your keytab file, username with your
  >   username, and version# with the appropriate version number.
  >
  > Verify that the version is gone, and then in ktutil, enter:
  >
  > ```
  >   quit
  > ```
  >
  > To do the same thing using Heimdal Kerberos, use:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil -k mykeytab list
  >
  >   ...
  >   version# type username@ADS.IU.EDU
  >   ...
  >
  >   > ktutil -k mykeytab remove -V version# -e type username@ADS.IU.EDU
  > ```
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Merging keytab files**
  >
  > If you have multiple keytab files that need to be in one place, you
  >   can merge the keys with the ktutil command.
  >
  > To merge keytab files using MIT Kerberos, use:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil
  >   ktutil: read_kt mykeytab-1
  >   ktutil: read_kt mykeytab-2
  >   ktutil: read_kt mykeytab-3
  >   ktutil: write_kt krb5.keytab
  >   ktutil: quit
  > ```
  >
  > Replace mykeytab-(number) with the name of each keytab file. The final
  >   merged keytab would be krb5.keytab .
  >
  > To verify the merge, use:
  >
  > ```
  >   klist -k krb5.keytab
  > ```
  >
  > To do the same thing using Heimdal Kerberos, use:
  >
  > ```
  >   > ktutil copy mykeytab-1 krb5.keytab
  >   > ktutil copy mykeytab-2 krb5.keytab
  >   > ktutil copy mykeytab-3 krb5.keytab
  > ```
  >
  > Then, to verify the merge, use:
  >
  > ```
  >   ktutil -k krb5.keytab list
  > ```
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Copying a keytab file to another computer**
  >
  > The keytab file is independent of the computer it's created on, its
  >   filename, and its location in the file system. Once it's created, you
  >   can rename it, move it to another location on the same computer, or
  >   move it to another Kerberos computer, and it will still function. The
  >   keytab file is a binary file, so be sure to transfer it in a way that
  >   does not corrupt it.
  >
  > If possible, use SCP or another secure method to transfer the keytab
  >   between computers. If you have to use FTP, be sure to issue the bin
  >   command from your FTP client before transferring the file. This will
  >   set the transfer type to binary so the keytab file will not be
  >   corrupted.
  >
  > [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214043244/http://kb.iu.edu/data/aumh.html#create)

Because of this information, I'm now using the following script to do the autologin with a supplied kerberos keytab file and it works great!!

```
DISPLAY= su mythtv -c "HOME=/var/lib/mythtv KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_mythtv_tty7 /usr/bin/kinit -k -t /var/lib/mythtv/mythtv.keytab mythtv"
export KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_mythtv_tty7
/sbin/mingetty --delay=2 --autologin=mythtv tty7
```

---

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: Who needs links or web.archive.org, etc. anyway~